# Como pegar os valores da propriedade de um objeto criado com uma função construtora e agrupar em um array?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Eu tenho essa duas funções construtoras que devem criar três passageiros e uma carroça e eu preciso criar um metodo que quando um passageiro é adicionado a carroça ele adiciona o seu nome no array passenger da carroça e diminui a capacidade em 1.
Eu já fiz o método diminuir a capacidade, mas não consigo pegar o nome dos passageiros. Eu poderia pegar os nomes dos três passeiros criados e dar push no array, mas teria uma forma de fazer com que qualquer nome criado com com essa construtora possa ser adicionado ao array.

```
function Traveler(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.food = 1;
    this.isHealthy = true;
}

function Wagon(capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.passengers = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o nome do passageiro acessando o valor da propriedade `name` de cada instância dos passageiros.

Adicionando um passageiro, basta diminuir a capacidade da carroça.

Para isso pode ser adicionado um método à essa classe usando [protótipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```js
function Traveller(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.food = 1;
    this.isHealthy = true;
}

function Wagon(capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.passengers = [];
}

Wagon.prototype.addTraveller = function (traveller) {
    if (this.capacity === 0) {
      return document.write(`<p>Essa carroça não tem mais capacidade, passageiro ${traveller.name} não foi adicionado.</p>`);
    }
    this.passengers.push(traveller.name);
    this.capacity--;
    document.write(`<p>Adicionado passageiro ${traveller.name}<p>`);
}

Wagon.prototype.removeTraveller = function (traveller) {
    let index = this.passengers.findIndex((v) => v === traveller.name);
    if (index < 0) {
      document.write(`<p>Passageiro ${traveller.name} não estava na carroça, portanto não foi removido<p>`);
      return
    }
    
    this.passengers.splice(index, 1);
    this.capacity++;
    document.write(`<p>Removido passageiro ${traveller.name}<p>`);
}

Wagon.prototype.output = function () {
  document.write(`<p>Capacidade: ${this.capacity} - ${JSON.stringify(this.passengers)}</p>`);
}

const wagon = new Wagon(3);
const traveller1 = new Traveller('Jon');
const traveller2 = new Traveller('Arya');
const traveller3 = new Traveller('Daenerys');
const traveller4 = new Traveller('Ned');
const traveller5 = new Traveller('Tyrion');

wagon.output();

wagon.addTraveller(traveller1);
wagon.output();

wagon.addTraveller(traveller2);
wagon.output();

wagon.addTraveller(traveller3);
wagon.output();


wagon.removeTraveller(traveller4);
wagon.output();

wagon.removeTraveller(traveller3);
wagon.output();

wagon.addTraveller(traveller4);
wagon.output();

wagon.addTraveller(traveller5);
wagon.output();
```